# Question feed updates mess up question's order

Tags: discussion, bug, ios-app

In SE iOS app we've got a *question feed* that one can scroll to see more questions. It's generally OK, but it has a tiny, but very annoying bug (or probably, disfunction?)

Imagine you're scrolling this feed up (*) and stumble upon a question that looks interesting to you. You stop scrolling and tap this question. But if the feed's near its end and should be updated to get more questions, they're loaded, but *the question you wanted to take a look at just vanishes* since tons of other questions are stuffed into the feed and it gets pushed up and you'll have to scroll all over again to find it. What's more, sometimes this question disappears completely. Certainly, it *is somewhere on SO*, but not in the feed anymore.

To my mind, it'd be great if the SE app developers made question feed updates *more smooth*. Also, it'd be awesome if the questions you were looking at at the moment of update *stayed right there* (in the current version they're pushed up and new questions come in) while the freshly-loaded questions stayed in the bottom.

<sub>* I mean, you scroll up (moving your finger upwards) to get the questions that are *below* the ones you're looking at at the moment</sub>

Comment: Just got the 'Tumbleweed' badge for this question :( Supposing nobody finds this annoying